# Why my calculator always reports "syntax error"?

Tags: yacc, lex

It's based on [this article](http://www.mactech.com/articles/mactech/Vol.06/06.04/ParsingwithYACC/index.html) but uses `lex` instead of implement it myself.

But I've tried various expressions like `2+3`,all failed...

lex:

```c
0   {
        yylval = atoi(yytext);
    }

[1-9][0-9]* {
                yylval = atoi(yytext);
                return NUM;
            }

[-+*/()]    {
                return *yytext;
            }

[ \t\n]+    ;

.           yyerror("Unknown character");
```

yacc:

```c
%start prob

%token NUM

%%

prob : expr '\n'
{
    printf("\t=%X\n", $1);
    return 0;
}
;

expr : expr '+' term
{
    $$ = $1 + $3;
}
| expr '-' term
{
    $$ = $1 - $3;
}
| term
{
    $$ = $1;
}
;

term : term '*' NUM
{
    $$ = $1 * $3;
}
| term '/' NUM
{
    $$ = $1/$3;
}
| '(' expr ')'
{
    $$ = $2;
}
| NUM
{
    $$ = $1;
}
;

%%
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because of :

```
[ \t\n]+    ;
```

Move `\n` to `[-+*/()]`.

Answer (score 0):

first upon remove test for 0 i.e.

```
0   {
    yylval = atoi(yytext);
}
```

this wont help you.this should work now.